# Can we travel faster than light?

Tags: special-relativity, reference-frames, faster-than-light

Consider two cars going in opposite direction one at speed $c/2$ and other just greater than $c/2$, then one bus will appear to other moving at speed more than $c$. How can an object travel at speed more than light?

Comment: It can't. You need to use relativistic velocity addition formulas or Lorentz transformations. You are thinking classically (Galilean) but asking  a relativistic problem. Check this out http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/relativ/einvel.html

Comment: The duplicate I've suggested is itself a duplicate, but it's the closest match I found to your question.